# Have ssh -Y follow you through su

Tags: unix, ssh

I have a question regarding the -Y option when ssh into a Unix machine (Sun OS specifically). I am aware that this option allows you to push graphics to your machine (ie: gedit) the only problem is that as soon as I su to any other use this option doesn't transfer. My question is this, is there a way to keep this option active after you su to another user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  When you log into your account, type:

```
xauth list $DISPLAY
```

Which should give you something along the lines of:

```
host.example.com/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  3d1e4422a15470a236770dedf87335b0
```

`su` over to the other account, make sure the `DISPLAY` variable is set correctly (probably by setting it by hand), and then run:

```
xauth add host.example.com/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  3d1e4422a15470a236770dedf87335b0
```

And you should be all set.  This is described in more detail [here](http://xpt.sourceforge.net/techdocs/nix/conn/ssh/ssh04-SshAndX/single/), and also [here](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/494).